# regex,how to filter any@any: to any@any without '' : ''?

Tags: python, regex

regex,how to filter `any@any:` to `any@any` without `:` ?

I need a Python regex code to use for Word List Updater 2.7 i want to filter any mail i.e:

```
a@earthlink.net:

b@ozemail.com.au:
```

final result:

```
a@earthlink.net

b@ozemail.com.au
```

i have the following regex -

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-_!@#$%^&*.,?]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)
```

which filters `any@any.any`

```
a@earthlink.net

b@ozemail.com.au
```

and not

```
a@earthlink.net:
```

Comment: is ':' always at end ?

Comment: If it's consistently at the end of the resulting string, why not just remove it (or replace it with an empty string)?

Comment: You do not need regular expressions, just use rstrip as @Padraic Cunningham suggests below.

Answer (score 0):

Juts `rstrip` it off, if it is there it will be removed if not nothing will get stripped:

```
"anyaddr@any.domain:".rstrip(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

see this [email regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

```
emails = ('b@ozemail.com.au', 'a@earthlink.net','a@earthlink.net:')

reg = r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b"

 for email in emails:
    print(re.match(reg,email).group())
```

output;
b@ozemail.com
a@earthlink.net
a@earthlink.net

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems needlessly complex. The username part of an email ID must contain only alphabets, numbers and periods. Some mail services allow hyphens and underscores. But gmail strictly demands only the first three.

Therefore your regex would be as follows:

```
'[\w.]+@[\w.]+'
```

This will also eliminate you ':' problem, because colon ':' is not considered as a word character (\w) by the regex engine.

You can use the findall() method from the re module to find all the email IDs in the string you supply. It will return you a list.

```
filtered_emails = re.findall(r'[\w.]+@[\w.]+', string)

for email in filtered_emails:
    print email
```

[Google python class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) has really good tutorials and examples on regex. Go take a visit.

Comment: the result is this: john@yahoo.com:1234 , john@yahoo.com, etc...not working

Comment: Oh.... yep..... well you can modify the regex a little bit.     r'[\w.]+@[a-z.]+'  . This will work fine.

Comment: Downlaod plz Word List Updater 2.7 is easy to find on google and u can try urself, is not working, wait i will give u my own tool: https://www.mediafire.com/?cs1ncicsw12p0zu   , try now please

Comment: not working u can download and try yourself with my tool, man , thanks anyway